# Is it possible to import my database on another server?

Tags: mysql, linux, import, foreign-keys, export

I am working on a database which is placed on an online server (Linux). I had to do big changes to this database so I moved (by export then import) this database to a local one I created (Windows Server).

After working these last days on the local database I decided that the work was already done so I exported the local database and imported it to the live one but I could not. It gave me error related to foreign-key:

> #1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

The table `phpmyadmin` said that was the one with some errors was `printprices` and these are the create tables I have for `printprices` and the other tables which could have some relation to the error:

```
CREATE TABLE `printprices` (
  `STYLE` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `DIFICULTAD` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `NCOLORES` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PROVEEDOR` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SIZECM2MAX` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `MINQ` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `MAXQ` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `PRECIO` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `PRECIOPRV` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `MINWORK` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  `MINWORKPRV` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`STYLE`,`DIFICULTAD`,`NCOLORES`,`PROVEEDOR`,`SIZECM2MAX`,`MINQ`),
  KEY `FK_PRINT` (`STYLE`,`DIFICULTAD`,`NCOLORES`,`PROVEEDOR`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_PRINT` FOREIGN KEY (`STYLE`, `DIFICULTAD`, `NCOLORES`, `PROVEEDOR`) REFERENCES `print` (`STYLE`, `DIFICULTAD`, `NCOLORES`, `PROVEEDOR`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 


CREATE TABLE `print` (
  `STYLE` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `DIFICULTAD` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `NCOLORES` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `PROVEEDOR` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `CFC` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`STYLE`,`DIFICULTAD`,`NCOLORES`,`PROVEEDOR`),
  KEY `FK_PRINTPROV` (`PROVEEDOR`),
  KEY `FK_PRINTSTYLE` (`STYLE`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_PRINTPROV` FOREIGN KEY (`PROVEEDOR`) REFERENCES `proveedores` (`CODIPRV`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_PRINTSTYLE` FOREIGN KEY (`STYLE`) REFERENCES `printstyle` (`CODISTY`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 


CREATE TABLE `printstyle` (
  `CODISTY` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `STYLE` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CODISTY`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


CREATE TABLE `proveedores` (
  `CODIPRV` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PROVEEDOR` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ENVIOPRICE` decimal(4,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `CARTONPRICE` decimal(4,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `LIMITPRICE` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CODIPRV`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: run command "SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS" and check for the "LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR" field, report what you see there. It may help you or us identify the problem!

Comment: I am quite lost, I have never done this before.

Comment: In your phpmyadmin interface, go to 'SQL' tab and write "SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS". Then click 'Options' and check the option "Full Texts". Finally click "GO". If you tried to import your tables in the same session, and you got the '1215' error, there will be a "LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR" field which will give more information about that error.

Comment: It seems I don't have access for that and I haven't found where can I get privileges for that . `#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the PROCESS privilege(s) for this operation`

Comment: You will have to log in mysql as a root user, I was under the impression that you had those kind of privileges (since you could export/import the database)

Comment: That database is stored on a hosted server and it looks like the user which is automatically created after creating a database does not have full privileges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found out why it wasn't working:

The problem was I was trying to upload my database on a `Mysql`, hosted with Linux, which is case sensitive. My `foreign keys` were stored on capital letter but my tables were not.

When `Mysql` from Linux read the file and tried to delete a table before creating it, the table wasn't deleted because the name wasn't exactly the same as it had been already stored in capital before.

The solution was to edit the export file and change all table names from lower case to capital.